# Are there any effective many-to-one algorithms without using modulo operator?

Tags: algorithm

Given a set containing 1~N and I tried to **fairly** map them into one of M slots (N > M). I think this is many-to-one mapping problems.

The naive solution is using modulo operator, given N = 10 and M = 3, we can do mapping like:

```
N   M

1 % 3 = 1 (assign to 2nd slot)
2 % 3 = 2 (assign to 3rd slot)

...

9 % 3 = 0 (assign to 1st slot)
```

This solution seems pretty fair but takes expensive operator. Are there any existing algorithm to take care of this kind of problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Modulus is not an expensive operator.  But if you really want something cheaper, masking out bits is another reduction operator.

Comment: What are the constraints of the problem? Do you have to assign all at once / in parallel or just one after the other? Since you are worried about the performance of a single operator, what is the practical implementation platform by which to measure operator/algorithm performance?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, they will be sequentially assigned and this be implemented in C. This is part of component in my system and I try to figure out are there any better existing solution (e.g. using bit mask) than modulo-way

Comment: You're asking for a micro-optimisation, but you don't really state the details of the problem making it impossible to answer in any disciplined way. The input seems to be N and M, but what is the result? For what computer system is this code to run on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is debatable if `%` is a slow operator, but bit manipulation is faster. If you are happy to map into a number of bins that are a power of two, M=2^k, then you mask out the lower k bits

```
x & (M - 1);
```

or

```
x & ((1 << k)-1);
```

If the number of bins is a Mersenne prime, M = 2^s-1  there is also a quick way to get the remainder:

```
unsigned int mod_Mersenne(unsigned int x, unsigned int s)
{
     unsigned int p = (1 << s) - 1;
     unsigned int y = (x & p) + (x >> s);
     return (y > p) ? y - p : y;
}
```

I believe you can also do it branchless, but I don’t remember how.

If you need to bin the numbers in sequence, as in your example, and if you can choose M to be the word size of a smaller integer, you can also exploit that unsigned integer types handle overflow like modulo, so you could do something like

```
unsigned char i = 0; // M = 256 (probably)
for (int j = 0; j < N; j++, i++)
    bin[i]++; // do something with the bin
```

When `i` moves past the size of an unsigned char it wraps around to zero.

This is only guaranteed for unsigned, so don’t use a signed integer here. And be ware that a char doesn’t have to be eight bit, but you can check. (It is very likely to be).

Generally, unsigned arithmetic behaves as if you have already taken modulo, so you can exploit that if you can choose N to match a word size.

Answer (score 1):

Modulus `m = n % M` with constant `M` is typically implemented directly from the definition

```
m = n - M*(n/M)
```

which can be easily regarded expensive - at least in comparison to bit masking.

For division by a constant, sophisticated compilers typically implement another algorithm (developed by Montgomery), which contains first an approximation by reciprocal multiplication, then one or two adjustment stages to fix some corner cases, where the first approximations `m' = (n * R) >> K)` can be off by one (or possibly two).

This suggests a few improvements:

- carefully skipping the adjustment stages, offsetting the `(1<<k)/M` with some value, so that the top bits of the product of the new coefficient `0 <= m'' = (n * R) >> K < M` are purely within the wanted range.
- considering if the mapping function actually needs to be modulus: if it's sufficient that `0<= m'' < M`, which leaves out the need to multiply the `m = n - M*m''`.

For N=10, M=3, the suitable coefficients are K=256/3 = 85, k = 8, which maps the values `n=0..9` to `m=0..2` with `m = n * 85 >> 8` as

```
//  n = 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
//  m = 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2   (approximation of n/3)
```

(The smallest numbers to get the same set of output values is btw K=16/3 = 5, k = 4).